# Dockerfile COPY takes a stale copy of the file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following sequence of commands in my Dockerfile; note the replacement **in place** by *sed*:

```
RUN sed -i "s/replace this/with that/g" ./dir/file.yaml
COPY ./dir/file.yaml /usr/src/app/node_modules/serve-swagger-editor/node_modules/swagger-editor/spec-files/
```

This runs ALMOST good, that is the `file.yaml` gets copied to the target location, but:

- `./dir/file.yaml` contains changes done by *sed*,
- `/usr/src/.../spec-files/file.yaml` does not.

It turns out that this workaround fixes the COPY problem:

```
RUN sed -i "s/replace this/with that/g" ./dir/file.yaml
RUN cp ./dir/file.yaml /usr/src/app/node_modules/serve-swagger-editor/node_modules/swagger-editor/spec-files/
```

Would anyone explain this bizarre behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

`RUN` executes command within the container, so `sed` is applied to the file `./dir/file.yaml` that is in it. You probably have a/the same file in your `WORKDIR/dir/file.yaml` ([WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)), that explains why the second option works.

The `COPY` in your first version overrides the `/usr/src/app/node_modules/serve-swagger-editor/node_modules/swagger-editor/spec-files/` file with the `./dir/file.yaml` that is in your host build directory. This one has not been affected by the `sed` command before, as it is outside the container.

So what you can do is `COPY` the file first inside the container, and then use your `RUN` command to modify it. Or modify it before running `docker build`.

Comment: or, in one `RUN` do the sed and the cp, with a `;` between them (and it avoids several RUN, as explained in the Dockerfile best practices https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/